# NgRepeat filtering complex structure

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been given a complex JSON object to display inside Angular and I'd like to filter it into two lists after having drilled down into the object.

The object structure is:

```
{
  foo:
  {
    bar:
    {
      showA: { value: true, type: 'A' },
      showB: { value: false, type: 'A' },
      showC: { value: true, type: 'A' }
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to achieve a list of "false" and "true".

In this case:

Disabled:

- showB - Type: A

Enabled:

- showA - Type: A
- showC - Type: A

I can't filter the object and also can't obtain the "key" of the objects, e.g. "showA".

My attempt of using:

```
item in profile['foo']['bar'] | filter: { value: false }
```

Accesses the correct objects but I can't filter or get the "key" of it.

Here is a broken plunkr to demonstrate:

http://plnkr.co/edit/9NniQdo213AuEbf0pghA?p=preview

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this working punkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/TdM9P592OXd6Bx81Bmbt?p=preview

It uses a custom filter, `myFilter`, which makes the filtering task pretty simple. `myFilter` returns a new object with only the objects having value equal to the value given as second argument to the filter.

```
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(bar, value) {
    var r = {};
    for (var key in bar) {
      if (bar[key].value == value) {
        r[key] = bar[key];
      }
    }
    return r;
  }
});
```

To get the key with `ng-repeat`, use the following syntax:

```
    <li ng-repeat="(key, item) in profile['foo']['bar'] | myFilter:false">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.value" /> {{ key }}
    </li>
```

If you can alter the structure of `$scope.profile`, the filtering task would be easier with this structure:

```
bar: [
    {name: 'ShowA', value: false, type: 'A'},
    ...
]
```